# Using python-pptx, how can I replace copied images in a slide with different images?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

The following code is commonly shared for how to replace an image in a powerpoint using `python-pptx`:

```py
import collections
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation, parts
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE

prs = Presentation('test.pptx')

image_to_replace = parts.image.Image.from_file('test.png')
replacement_image = parts.image.Image.from_file('new.png')

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.PICTURE:    
            slide_part, rId = shape.part, shape._element.blip_rId
            image_part = slide_part.related_part(rId)
            if image_to_replace.blob == image_part.blob:
                image_part.blob = replacement_image._blob


prs.save('new.pptx')
```

However, I am having an issue where if there are multiple copies of the same image in a slide, I cannot replace *just one* of those images. Since they share a `rId2`, they are all being replaced using the `blob`. I have created a [sample repo](https://github.com/ethanj20/sample-python-pptx) with functioning code to further explain my issue. I have also commented on the GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/116).

How can I replace just one of the copied images at a time rather than all of them?

Any help is much appreciated.

See the sample repo for an example of the issue I am running into.